# Oracle BI XML RTF Removing blank page

Tags: oracle, rtf, bi-publisher

I need your help with my RTF file for Oracle BI Publisher.

I have an RTF report that contains 2 types of page size, portrait and landscape. The problem I have is that if the pages are empty, it continues to display the pages. I do not have spaces between the pages, I made sure of it, and I have a condition that does not seem to be respected with a . This makes me this problematic only on this change between portrait and landscape. Is there any way I can tell if the landscape page is empty, do not display it?

Right now, my RTF is like this. 2 pages portraits -> 1 page landscape -> 3 pages portraits. I want to hide my empty pages, I get there for the first 2 pages, but it does not do for the landscape page and the next one that comes back to portrait.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you share your template?

Comment: sorry i can't share it because of privacy rights! :(

Comment: It will be hard for someone to help you if you can't provide the technical portion of the template that is causing problems. Is it the template that has the privacy rights, or the data?

Comment: Yes, i know it will not be easy. The Template has the privacy rights! If i extract the RTF to XML, i see i have 3 page sequence master-reference like this : <fo:page-sequence master-reference="master0"><fo:page-sequence master-reference="master1"><fo:page-sequence master-reference="master2"> i want to hide the master1 if data not found (master 1 is the landscape page.

Comment: Can you come up with/build a simplified template that has the same failure reason, but does not have the parts that contain privacy rights? That way you can share it.